# Add/Remove gridlines in cells containing data in the cells

Tags: excel

I am creating a work planner using Excel. The user selects a specific name from a drop down menu and it displays the projects. I want a table/gridline to be displayed. I would like it to add a gridline which automatically shows/hides when a name is selected but the height should be dependent on the rows of data. So if there are a 5 projects the table should be 5 columns long.

I have implemented a formula using Conditional Formatting (=NOT(ISBLANK(D6))), but the table still shows if I select the default option which shows no names.

Answer (score 0):

Bit tricky without knowing what's in D6! - but presume it's your dropdown... in which case don't you want this an absolute reference $D$6?

One other thing to try is having multiple rules, so setup conditional formatting so that ISBLANK(D6) then no borders (make sure it's the first rule and to tick 'stop if true' to stop it running through to your NOT(ISBLANK) rule)